# Use mogrify to resize images larger than AxB and leave untouched other files

Tags: imagemagick

I use the following command:

```
mogrify -verbose -resize "1024x1024>" *
```

However this command converts all images found even those less than 1024x1024

This is an example output:

```
AAsmall.png PNG 114x183 114x183+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 8.15KB 0.000u 0:00.000
AAsmall.png PNG 114x183 114x183+0+0 8-bit sRGB 16.8KB 0.010u 0:00.000
image2.png PNG 736x1041 736x1041+0+0 8-bit sRGB 332KB 0.030u 0:00.040
image2.png PNG 736x1041=>724x1024 724x1024+0+0 8-bit sRGB 397KB 0.320u 0:00.320
```

You can see that file "AAsmall.png" is still converted, although it is less than 1024x1024..
Should I use identify and then pipe its output to mogrify?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps mogrify does not support the > I would try a convert on AAsmall.png and see what it does. convert AAsmall.png -resize "1024x1024>" result.png

Comment: Did you actually check the size of AAsmall.png after this command? If there is no resize IM will just duplicate the line with basic info. Note that there is no => string.

Comment: @rostok, yes AAsmall.png is modified (size and timestamp)